# How to add a title in a GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

I have got 2 different `GridLayout` of buttons. They represent a game board and I like to add a title and a border to the `GridLayout` to distinguish the user's board from the PC's board. The `Gridlayout` is done, but I don't know how to add the title.

Comment: Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for titled borders.

Comment: You don't  add titles and borders to layout managers ... you add them to JComponents. I'm assuming your buttons are contained in a content pane of some sort, a JPanel maybe?....you can add your titled border to that content pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Code below:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridLayout Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Create the two grids
        JPanel grid1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2,2,2));
        JPanel grid2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2,2,2));

        // Create borders
        Border empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
        Border blackLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        CompoundBorder line = new CompoundBorder(empty, blackLine);
        Border grid1Border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(line, "Grid 1");
        Border grid2Border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(line, "Grid 2");

        //Grid 1
        grid1.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
        grid1.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
        grid1.add(new JButton("Button 3"));
        grid1.add(new JButton("Button 4"));
        grid1.setBorder(grid1Border); 

        //Grid 2
        grid2.add(new JButton("Button 5"));
        grid2.add(new JButton("Button 6"));
        grid2.add(new JButton("Button 7"));
        grid2.add(new JButton("Button 8"));
        grid2.setBorder(grid2Border);

        frame.getContentPane().add(grid1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(grid2);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Note: you can find the full list of constructors for further customization of the border (like color, position of text, justification of text) [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createTitledBorder).